# mysql how to join a tables by multiple different conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 `table`

```
product

id_product,price,etc
```

relation

```
id,relation1,relation2,relation3,...
```

I want get any product where id=relation1,...

How to write it in `sql`?

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE id_product = relation1,relation2,relation3,...
```

Comment: Question title isn't a proper title. It's not searchable or related to problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need an inner join and an IN statement :

```
SELECT * FROM product t
INNER JOIN relation s
    ON(t.id_product in(s.relation1,s.relation2,s.relation3))
```